# Dynamic where clause in custom query JPA

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

**How to pass where clause whitout using query dsl or custom repository?**

```
public interface PlTransactionsRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<PlTransactions, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<PlTransactions> {
      @Query(value = "SELECT a FROM PlTransactions :whereClause")
      List<PlTransactions> selectTrxForRecon(@Param("whereClause") Integer whereClause);
}
```

Comment: You can't do this.  Please post your intended query.

Comment: How would you even construct this "custom where clause"? If you need to build it dynamically you'd be concatenating Strings anyway. Might as well just use the custom repository as it will be in the right place.

Comment: Yeah i was using custom actually but i got problem where the entity can't be read. What i actually want to reach is to get sum value of specific column like i was mentioned in [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73471942/org-hibernate-hql-internal-ast-querysyntaxexception-transactions-is-not-mapped).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamic where queries, you shouldn't use JPQL but Criteria API or the Spring Data JPA `JpaSpecificationExecutor`

If you implement `JpaSpecificationExecutor` you'll get find methods where you can pass a `Specification`. A Specification will form the dynamic where clause.

Please find more information in the documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications